# How to get last 1 hour to last 10 days data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get data within a range which starts a hour ago. As an example if now time is 08.00 AM, I need to get all the data within 07.00 AM to last 10 days. I have tried with `datesub` function as below, But seems this is wrong because the date(now()) and date(now()-interval 1 hour) are both same.. Can someone show me how to get this?

```
.....and date(time)>date(date_sub((now()-interval 1 hour), interval 10 day)) group by ds.....
```

Comment: date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), interval 10 day)  see if  this help

Comment: Simply now() - interval 1 hour - interval 10 day? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52a2ef1d7eb0bcdc6f9c45ea86c6beb8

Comment: Both above answers were not correct...

Comment: These are comments, no answers, their purpose is to clarify the requirements. According to the linked fiddle, the outcome is what you asked for. If you still have issues, please provide sample input and outcome or even better use the fiddle above to create a replicable setup and share the new url

Comment: What is the data type of your field "time"? To get a data range you want, it has to be timestamp or datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `time` field in your query is either timestamp or datetime.

```
... and time between cast(concat(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 day), ' 00:00:00') as datetime) and DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

Hope this will help.